# Trigonometric equations with four roots

Tags: trigonometry

If $x,y,z,k$ be the roots of the equation 
         $$\sin(\theta+\alpha) =a \sin(2\theta)$$
no two of which differ by a multiple of $2\pi$, prove that
         $$x+y+z+k=(2n+1)\pi$$

Comment: I assume the equation is in $\theta$, and $a$ and $\alpha$ are constants?

Comment: is there a typo? $$\sin(\theta+\alpha) =\alpha \sin(2\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how the problem cane into being.

On simplification we have $$\sec\theta\cos\alpha+\csc\theta\sin\alpha=2a\  \ \ \  (1)$$

Like  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner,

using [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution), $$\sec\theta=\dfrac{1+t^2}{1-t^2},\csc\theta=\dfrac{1+t^2}{2t}$$ where $\tan\dfrac\theta2=t$

Setting these values in $(1)$ and on rearrangement,

$$t^4(\sin\alpha)-t^3(\cdots)+t^2(0)-t(\cdots)-\sin\alpha$$

Using $\tan(A+B+C+D)$ [formula](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol535.html),$$\tan\left(\dfrac x2+\dfrac y2+\dfrac z2+\dfrac k2\right)=\infty$$ as $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\tan\dfrac x2\tan\dfrac y2=\dfrac0{\sin\alpha}=?$$

and $$\tan\dfrac x2\tan\dfrac y2\tan\dfrac z2\tan\dfrac k2=\dfrac{-\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha}=?$$

Can you take it from here?